# Instant reverse HTTP proxy from a Linux command-line

Tags: linux, bash, http, reverse-proxy

There is a nice trick to instantly serve contents of a current working directory by HTTP locally:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This command launches HTTP server at *:8000, serving $PWD contents.

I'm looking for something similar, but for setting up a reverse-proxy.

Something like this:

```
$ instant-reverse-http-proxy --listen-on 'http://localhost:8000/' --proxy-to 'https://example.com/path'`
```

So that

```
$ GET http://localhost:8000/bar
```

would fetch `https://example.com/path/bar`.

Any clues?

Comment: For the http to http only case, tinyproxy works. Simple and minimal dependencies. For http to https, you'll need to drag in openssl somewhere, and also support rewriting host header and sni. So either socat or mitmproxy depending on your complexity. And moving up from that you have squid and nginx as full-blown overkill.

Note for mitmproxy, the default is to mirror localhost/* to remote/*. If you want to map index to some directory on remote, you can write a handler to rewrite it.

Comment: Maybe stunnel would also work. But I think the best solution here is writing a few 100 lines of go code, maybe something like https://gist.github.com/JalfResi/6287706

After trying out both mitmproxy and socat, I think just making use of Go stdlib is much cleaner, and gives you whatever configurability you need (e.g. add or replace headers, buffer or don't buffer, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/)?

```
# socat TCP-LISTEN:80,reuseaddr,fork,su=nobody TCP:www.dmz.mydomain.org:80
```

(from [lorgor.blogspot](http://lorgor.blogspot.com/2009/11/socat.html) and [MIT](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/machine/penguin-lust/src/socat-1.7.1.2/EXAMPLES))

```
# socat -vv OPENSSL-LISTEN:443,cert=cert.pem,cafile=cacert.pem, \
cert=cert.key,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:192.168.34.65:80
```

(from https://www.buntschu.net/blog/?p=242)

Comment: The last link is dead, please correct for future comers

Comment: I think the first doesn't do what the OP asked, and the second does the opposite.
This should do it:
`socat TCP-LISTEN:8000,reuseaddr,fork ssl:example.com:443`.  Throw in a `verify=0` if the certificate can't or doesn't have to be verified.

Answer (score 5):

I was faced with the exact same problem and became frustrated with the software that was around (and still am) and so I made **[proxyboi](https://github.com/svenstaro/proxyboi)**. Its purpose is to be an instant command-line only proxy without a configuration file. Give it a spin. Hopefully it helps you and others looking for a simple instant reverse proxy.

Answer (score 5):

[mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) is a fully fledge proxy and http packet analysis tool. The best I've found so far.

For your use case:

```
mitmproxy --listen-port 8000 --mode reverse:https://example.com/path
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a node module for that: https://github.com/cha0s/kiss-proxy. Supports command line arguments and a config file for more complex situations.

Only downside with kiss-proxy is that it looks slightly dated and may not run on newer versions of node.

Comment: could you give more detail than a link ?